# How to recover data from a formatted partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have 2 partitions on my hard drive, one with windows 7 and the other with ubuntu 16.04.1. I went to windows 7 and deleted the volume that has ubuntu on it, and now I installed linux mint 18 on it, is there any chance to recover some files that were stored on ubuntu ?

Comment: + we don't accept questions related to mint.

Comment: As long as files are not overwritten by your new installation there is a chance to recover them.

Comment: The os is fresh, i've only installed sublime text and chromium browser. how can I recover files?

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, no, there's no way to recover data in the partition you overwrote with Mint 18.

Technically, it may be possible to recover some *bits and pieces* of the data (maybe even whole files, if you haven't stored anything in the /home folder under Mint) using forensic methods, but in practice the cost of paying someone to do so or the learning curve of finding and learning to use the software for this are beyond the worth of most personal data.